# replace a line in xml file using ansible

Tags: ansible

Please help me with your guidance here.

I want to comment a line in one config file and need to uncomment the other lline using ansible.

My file content as below.

---

```
    `<include location="conf/basicUserRegistry.xml"/>`  

          this i want to comment 

`<!--include location="conf/ldapUserRegistry.xml"/-->`

         this line i want to uncomment
```

---

I tried with the below play book and its not showing any error even though its not changing any changes to the file.

```
- name: enable LDAP
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
   - name: disbale basic user-registry
     lineinfile:
       path: /opt/IBM/605CLM/JazzTeamServer/server/liberty/servers/clm/server.xml
       regexp: '^\s*<include location="conf/basicUserRegistry.xml">.*$'
       line: '<!--include location="conf/basicUserRegistry.xml"-->;'
       backrefs: yes
     become: true
```

---

```
- name: enable LDAP USER_REGISTRY
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    lineinfile:
      dest: /opt/IBM/605CLM/JazzTeamServer/server/liberty/servers/clm/server.xml
      regexp: '^(.*)<!--include location="conf/ldapUserRegistry.xml"-->(.*)$'
      line: '<include location="conf/ldapUserRegistry.xml">;'
      backrefs: yes
```

---

Output:

PLAY [enable LDAP] ******************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [disbale basic user-registry] **************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0

Answer (score 2):

An arguably cleaner way to solve this would make use of the [Ansible `xml` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/xml_module.html).

Example (assuming your example showed the complete file):

```
tasks:
  - xml:
      file: server.xml
      xpath: /include
      attribute: location
      value: conf/ldapUserRegistry.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the code that you're looking for?

```
vars:
  mark_1: 'include location="conf/basicUserRegistry.xml"/'
  mark_2: 'include location="conf/ldapUserRegistry.xml"/'
tasks:
  - lineinfile:
      path: server.xml
      regex: "^<!--{{ mark_2 }}-->"
      line: "<{{ mark_2 }}>"
  - lineinfile:
      path: server.xml
      regex: "^<{{ mark_1 }}>"
      line: "<!--{{ mark_1 }}-->"
```

It's not idempotent! If the *regex* exists the *line* will replace the line found. If the *regex* doesn't exist the *line" will be added anyway. To make it idempotent use *replace* module (example below).

Or, prehaps, this one ?

```
  - lineinfile:
      path: server.xml
      regex: ".{{ mark_2 }}."
      line: "<{{ mark_2 }}>"
  - lineinfile:
      path: server.xml
      regex: ".{{ mark_1 }}."
      line: "<!--{{ mark_1 }}-->"
```

or,

```
  - replace:
      path: server.xml
      regexp: "^<!--{{ mark_2 }}-->"
      replace: "<{{ mark_2 }}>"
  - replace:
      path: server.xml
      regexp: "^<{{ mark_1 }}>"
      replace: "<!--{{ mark_1 }}-->"
```

Comment: Hello Botka, I tried your first solutipon and it worked like a magic.. Its surprised me  and solution was perfect to fulfill my requirement here. Its a great answer and really appreciated your help

Comment: Hello Vowner, you're welcome! Be careful. First solution is not idempotent.

Comment: Hello Botka,First time it worked.. but again when i tried , its not changing the values in the xml file, but the ansible is showing as changed=2, but no change in the file .

Comment: I've commented the first example. Use *ansible-playbook --diff ...* to see what has been changed.

Comment: Hello Botka,Any suggestion here?

Answer (score 0):

Below is my playbook, Its not changing anything on the file

```
- name: LDAP Settings
 hosts: myserver
 vars:
   mark_1: 'include location="conf/basicUserRegistry.xml"/'
   mark_2: 'include location="conf/ldapUserRegistry.xml"/'
 tasks:
    - replace:
       path: /opt/IBM/server/liberty/servers/clm/server.xml
       regexp: "^<!--{{ mark_2 }}-->"
       replace: "<{{ mark_2 }}>"
    - replace:
       path: /opt/IBM/server/liberty/servers/clm/server.xml
       regexp: "^<{{ mark_1 }}>"
       replace: "<!--{{ mark_1 }}-->"
       backup: yes'
```